# How to fix gradle errors for Flutter android project which uses Firestore and messaging

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, messaging

I've created a Flutter app that uses Firebase services (auth, Firestore, messaging).

Everything went well with the iOS version, but I'm fighting with the Android version:

I've followed the official [setup guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup).

But no matter what configuration I use in the Gradle files - I get exceptions.

There are plenty of posts out there with different configurations - none of them worked for me, and some are outdated.

My latest configuration:
in android/build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

in android/app/build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
```

results in the following error:

```
> The library com.google.firebase:firebase-iid is being requested by various other libraries at [[18.0.0,18.0.0]], but resolves to 17.1.2. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

How and where can I find the right way to configure this android app to run with these Google services?

Comment: You should add the exceptions to the question

Answer (score 0):

Well, after many trials and errors, the right combination for me was:

pubspec.yaml

```
cloud_firestore: ^0.11.0+2
firebase_auth: ^0.11.1
firebase_messaging: ^5.0.1+1
```

android/build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
```

gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```